# Не работает JS из файла

Tags: javascript

Если вставить JS в тело страниццы, то он работает.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        //
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="/js/app.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            // Тут код
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Если я перемещаю его в `/js/app.min.js`, то не работает.

```
var jivo_loaded = false,
    buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.btn-buy, .btn-ask');

function jivo_onLoadCallback() {
    jivo_loaded = true;
    gtag('event', 'jivo_loaded');
}

function jivo_onIntroduction() {
    gtag('event', 'jivo_new_contact');
};

function showContactForm() {
    if (jivo_loaded) {
        jivo_api.open({ 
            start: 'menu',
        });
    } else {
        gtag('event', 'jivo_not_loaded');
    }

    if (this.dataset.color) {
        addColorToCookie(this.dataset.color);
        gtag('event', 'btn_buy');
    } else {
        gtag('event', 'btn_ask');
    }
}

function addColorToCookie(id) {
    this.axios
        .post('/update/' + id)
        .then((response) => {
            // 
        });
}

for (var index = 0; index < buttons.length; index++) {
    buttons[index].addEventListener('click', showContactForm);
}
```

Если в `/js/app.min.js` добавить `alert('ok')`, то он тоже прекрасно работает. То есть, что-то не то с моим кодом. Проблема явно в моем коде, только я не пойму что не так. Этот же код работает, когда он не в файле, а просто вставлен в тело страницы. Что не так?

**Update**

Разобрался немного. Функции, которые написал я — работают из файла. Проблема в том, что сейчас не срабатывают callback-функции от чата (Jivo). В частности jivo_onLoadCallback() и jivo_onIntroduction(). Есть ли варианты это исправить?

Comment: У вас `querySelectorAll` выполняется до того, как элементы отрендерятся. Поместите `script` в `head` и добавьте ему атрибут [defer](https://learn.javascript.ru/script-async-defer).

Comment: javaScript  пытается получить то, чего пока не существует. Иными словами он хочет поднять бумажку, зная, что она там будет, но ее пока там нет. Ждать он ее не хочет и дальше идет.

Comment: @nazarpunk Пробывал defer и пробывал перемстить скрипт в head - не  работает это

Comment: @СерегаМангышев как исправить?

Comment: Сам скрипт ниже всего (прям в конец  body)

Comment: @СерегаМангышев так и сделано. 0 реакции. ошибок в консоле тоже нет

Comment: Если код работает, тогда проблема с вашим кодом, хотя, если нет ошибок, попробуйте подебажить.

Comment: @СерегаМангышев Проблема явно в моем коде, только я не пойму что не так. Этот же код работает, когда он не в файле, а просто вставлен в тело страницы.

Comment: почитайте про DOMContentLoaded

Comment: @xmikex обновил вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

Вариант 1. Подключение скрипта перенести в подвал сайта после тега body

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        //
    </head>
    <body>
       
        
    </body>
    <script src="/js/app.min.js"></script>
    <script>
            // Тут код
    </script>
</html>
```

Вариант 2. Добавить обертку к вашему скрипту, которая будет говорить, что запускать скрипт надо после загрузки DOM.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded' , ()=>{ 
   //сюда вставить весь ваш код
})
```

Вариант 3. Используйте 'defer'. Скрипты с defer всегда выполняются, когда дерево DOM готово, но до события DOMContentLoaded:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
       <script defer src="/js/app.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        
        
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Спасибо, вы частично показание мне проблему. Обновил свой вопрос.

Comment: в вашем коде не видно где эти функции вызываются, и не видно никаких ошибок. Поэтому ничего нельзя сказать

Comment: Они в самом верху кода. Из-за того, что они не срабатывают jivo_loaded всегда false (должен становится true при успешной загрузки чата). Вот и получается, что никаких ошибок или изменений не происходит, потому что скрипт думает, что чат не загружен. Если вставить эти callback-функции в тело страницу то они срабатывают.

Comment: нужен пример кода, чтобы понять в результате чего они должны срабатывать

Comment: https://www.jivochat.com/api/ другого кода нет (